# how to create an ip range fast as fast as possible?

Tags: c#, for-loop, ip, ip-address, filestream

how to get the fastest result
i write the code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
             for (int j = 0; j < 256); j++)
               for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
                     for (int p = 0; p < 256; p++)
                     {
                         writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", i, j, k, p));
                     }
```

but my users told me that it is dammed slow. i dont have any idea how to boost  the progress. share the problem, maybe
 someone knows that. thanks.

Comment: what is writer? is it buffered stream? why `setText` for each ip?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You're writing from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 for some reason? Why do you need 4 indexes to do it? And why are you doing it in the first place?

Comment: Well, you are generating in the order of 40 GB of data, with 4294967296 `string.formats` and UI updates...of course it takes a while. Be more specific in the actual IPs you are generating. Do you need `9.0.45.2`?

Comment: that is the entire IPv4 range!!!!!!

Comment: @Jens isn't that IBM's IP?

Comment: Are you trying to so something like "netstat" to show all IP's in the local network? Cuz printing all possible IP addresses doesnt' make much sense

Comment: @bansi Good question, I just picked one at random that didn't seem useful in a typical application. Was too lazy to look it up ;-)

Comment: Well it was my users request. And SetText is a call back method I used in my thread. Just a sort of information about the process.

Comment: another question. where are you writing the stream output. you know the size of the output is more than 40GB

Comment: A text file. I put a selected range of ip. But the users still complaining about the speed. And I don't know why they should need such a huge file actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with IPAddressRange : https://www.nuget.org/packages/IPAddressRange/

But it will still be very long if you want to get all the ipv4 range!

```
var range = NetTools.IPAddressRange.Parse("192.168.0.10 - 192.168.10.20");
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  foreach (var item in range)
    {
        builder.Append(item);
    }
```

Comment: for the entire IPv4 range `StringBuilder` won't work. I don't think it can hold 40GB+ data

Comment: it s ok, i could write bunch of ips. using a Stream.Write(buffer, offset, count); as an example along side a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving 256 to the power of 4 items. That is over 4 billion calls to `setText`. If you *need* to create that many items, you have to look into the performance of setText. Your loop is performant enough and if you can optimize `setText` is unclear because I don't know what it does. But anything you do 4 billion times will be probably slow.